# Can I use DRY Concept for this code in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, web-deployment, dry

[image: Dry concept]

---

```
import React from "react";
import { Chip, Box } from '@mui/material';

const Browse = () => {

const [chip, setChip] = React.useState("all")

const handleClick = (event)=>{
  setChip(event.target.textContent);
  console.log(chip)
}


return (
  <Box mx={2} >
    <Box mt={2} sx={{display:"flex", gridGap:"20px", flexWrap:"wrap"}} >

    <Chip label="Price" sx={{color:"#FF005E"}}  onClick={handleClick} />
    <Chip label="Type of place" sx={{color:"#FF005E"}}  onClick={handleClick} />

    <Chip label="all"      variant={ "all" === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } onClick={handleClick} />
    <Chip label="mountain" variant={"mountain" === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } onClick={handleClick} />
    <Chip label="beach" variant={  "beach"  === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } onClick={handleClick} />
    <Chip label="island" variant={ "island" === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } onClick={handleClick} />
    <Chip label="desert" variant={ "desert" === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } onClick={handleClick} />
    <Chip label="plain" variant={  "plain"  === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } onClick={handleClick} />

    </Box>
  </Box>
);
};

export default Browse;
```

---

Help me any one, I need simple DRY Concept for my code.
I want to do something little animation with "meterial-ui" Chip Component.
so I am write code same code again and again.
so, please solve this anyone...
And thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of variants and then map:

```
  const chips = ["all","mountain","beach","island","desert","plain"]
    .map(variant => (
       <Chip
          key={variant}
          label="all"
          variant={ variant === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } 
          onClick={handleClick} />
    ))
```

Then you can use `{chips}` in your JSX below.

Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: make sure you have a key too

Comment: **very thanks :)**

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a method that create the `Chip`

```
const createChip = (label) => <Chip label={label} variant={ label === chip ? "filled": "outlined" } onClick={handleClick} />
```

Then call it like so

```
{createChip("all")}
{createChip("plain")}
...
```

or create an array

```
{["all", "plain"].map(createChip)}
```

but make sure each item has a key

```
<Chip key={label} ...
```

Comment: **very thanks :)**